# how to add a user defined condition to a PolicyDocument Statment in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

In AWS Cloudformation, I have a user defined condition, and a bucket policy being deployed:

```
Conditions:
  NotProd:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref Environment, production]]

...
BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Condition: NotProd
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - s3:getObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Resource: '*'
          - Action:
              - s3:getBucketLocation
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Resource: '*'
```

The above configuration has no problems, but when I try to add the condition such that the `s3:getBucketLocation` permission is only added if we're not in production, as follows:

```
BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - s3:getObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Resource: '*'
          - Action:
              - s3:getBucketLocation
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Resource: '*'
            Condition: NotProd
```

, then I get an error saying `Condition NotProd not used`. Is there any way I can somehow achieve my desired result of only adding `s3:getBucketLocation` when not in production without doing something like creating a separate bucket policy without the `s3:getBucketLocation` permission?

Comment: How did it go? Do you need more clarification on how to address your issue?

Comment: Sorry it worked - I've accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```
BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - s3:getObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Resource: '*'
          - !If
            - NotProd
            - Action:
                - s3:getBucketLocation
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: '*'
              Resource: '*'
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```